# Mockito - Specify more detailed method parameters for mock() and verify()

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following method

```
myMethod(QName param1, String[] param2, String... param3)
```

In my test I do

```
Mockito.when(this.myMock.myMethod(Mockito.any(QName.class), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
.thenReturn(this.someOtherMock);
```

Also I do verify like this

```
Mockito.verify(this.myMock).myMethod(Mockito.any(QName.class), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

But `Mockito.any()` is to broad, how to specify more detailed that is must be an array of `String`, or elipsis of `String` (same as array)?

In my code I call the `myMethod` like

```
myMethod(<..some QName value..>, new String[]{"someValue"},  <String... values passed into the outer method, so it's an array>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
Mockito.when(this.myMock.myMethod(Mockito.any(QName.class), ArgumentMatchers.<String[]>any(), ArgumentMatchers.<String[]>any())).thenReturn(this.someOtherMock);
```

Comment: I tried that meanwhile, doesn't work.

Comment: Try using ArgumentMatchers